# Cross-compiling C++11 code for Raspberry Pi

Tags: cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to port a large project, which makes heavy use of C++11 features, to the Raspberry Pi. The project uses CMAKE and I'm using crosstool-ng for the cross-compiling. I installed dependencies on the Pi and copied them locally, and I've managed to get CMAKE to find those. Some of the code builds properly and produces ARM output. However, most of the code fails with confusing GCC output that I'm pretty sure has to do with C++11/template support. For example, I get errors like this:

- `error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type` (the file in question includes <thread> and this error goes away if I also include <mutex>, not a requirement on x86 Ubuntu)
- `error: expected class-name before '{' token` (the line before { is: `template<typename _Res> class __basic_future : public std::__future_base`)
- `error: '__result_type' does not name a type` (this probably happens because of the error above)

These errors look like the ARM g++ compiler just doesn't like templates that much. The version of g++ being used is `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ (crosstool-NG 1.18.0) 4.7.3 20130102 (prerelease)`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: Here's what g++ looks like for one of the files in `ps`:

```
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ -DprojectCore_EXPORTS -fPIC
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/freetype2
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/glib-2.0
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/gtk-2.0
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/cairo
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/pango-1.0
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/atk-1.0
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/local/include
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/eigen3
-I/home/sagar/workspace/RaspberryPi/target_env/usr/include/flann
-I/home/sagar/workspace/project/include -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -Wno-deprecated -fPIC -g -O4
-o CMakeFiles/projectCore.dir/src/project/Core/Memory/Array2D.C.o -c /home/sagar/workspace/project/src/project/Core/Memory/Array2D.C
```

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I added the g++ command that's generated for one of the files. -std=c++0x is in there, and I think this is the same as c++11 at this point.

Comment: Well `std::mutex` is supposed to be defined in `<mutex>` (or [so it says here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)) so I don't think that's a bug - if anything the bug is that the x86 version includes the headers you didn't ask for, but I can't remember to what extent that's allowed anyway. But adding it in won't break x86 will it? Have you #included `<future>` for the other ones?

Comment: @Rup Good point about includes... though `<thread>` includes `<mutex>` and I think this passes through in the x86 build. I don't mind adding required includes as a solution, though. Including `<future>` didn't fix the other issues. It doesn't seem to like `template<typename _Res> class __basic_future : public std::__future_base` as a class declaration, but doesn't say why not.

Comment: Have you been able to fix the issue?

Comment: @ChristianRapp I solved another, related, issue I was having in another thread, and that solution might work for this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133977/stdshared-future-on-raspberry-pi-toolchain

Answer (score 2):

The only things I think are:

- set `-std=c++0x` param to `g++ compiler`
- link pthread (`-lpthread`)
- you must be sure that you're compiling for `armv6`

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying I am not sure about the fix for this error. But I had seen a similar error while working with C++ in RPi for a large image processing code. I couldn't fix it by installing all the dependencies in time. Instead I ended up moving the entire code to cloud  that was running windows server edition / windows 7 code where it compiled well. Just workaround idea if you are time bound!