# std::shared_future on Raspberry Pi toolchain

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to cross-compile a large project for the Raspberry Pi. I'm using a toolchain built by crosstool-ng, gcc version 4.7.3. The compilation chokes when it sees std::shared_future. I get this error:

```
test.cpp:5:27: error: aggregate 'std::shared_future<int> xxx' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

And here's the source file that generates that error:

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
  std::shared_future<int> xxx;
  return 0;
}
```

This same source file compiles successfully on the Rapsberry Pi itself. Is this a bug in the crosstool toolchain? Is there a workaround? How can I get this to successfully compile?

Comment: Are you sure the proper flags are passed to the compiler? Do you have any c++11 support at all?

Comment: Can you get `std::future`, `std::async` or `std::thread` to compile?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment, i just realized that the compiler would have complained about the include if c++11 was not there at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza Just tested these. std::thread works, not future or async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem with help from @backlash and the people on #gcc on Freenode. Crosstool-NG was building the toolchain for `armv7`, while the Raspberry Pi's compiler was compiling for `armv6`. Changing the "Architecture level" (Target options > Architecture level) to `armv6` allowed me to compile the sample code posted in my original question. This option adds a `--with-arch=armv6` to the configure flags for `gcc`. Hope this helps someone out in the future.

Answer (score 3):

To have `shared_future` implementation class and not just the forward declaration, you must have the following preprocessor condition equal to true : `#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1)
  && (ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE > 1)`

According to your previous answer to @juanchopanza, it seems that you have the following part of the condition equal to true : `if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1)` because it's necarry to have the implementation of `thread` class.

Finaly, we could say that this part of the condition is false `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE > 1`.

Comment: Why would it not be true? Is there a compiler flag I should pass? Note that the same code compiles on the rPi itself.

Comment: It appears to be a difference between your native compiler and cross compiler, so you should try to find out why they disagree.

Comment: `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE > 1` could be false cause of a bad configuration during crosstool-ng generation. So I think that you should rebuild your toolchain with a configuration which make `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE > 1` however I don't how.